# Time, space: real, lasting, own-able?

Tags: vipassana, abhidhamma, sila, dana

or uncertain, subject of change, a burden and not own- or control-able, not worthy to fall for?

Time to answer and give it up?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about time or space from the perspective of physics:

All conditioned and/or compounded things are impermanent, in the sense that they would arise and cease, and also change. Only Nibbana is not impermanent. Everything else, including space, time, matter and energy are subject to arising, ceasing and changing.

Space - If you have 1 m<sup>3</sup> of vacuumed empty space, is it permanent? If air or matter gets into it, then it's not empty anymore. According to quantum field theory, empty space is never truly empty, because quantum particles appear and disappear constantly.

In cosmology, space in the universe is said to be expanding, causing galaxies to become further apart as time goes by.

Time - Have you heard about time dilation? Time moves relatively a lot slower for an object that is moving closer to the speed of light. Therefore, time is conditioned.

The more we understand science, the more we understand that everything in the physical realm is impermanent, arising, ceasing and changing.

If you're talking about the realm of infinite space of *arupa jhana*, I believe that refers to a state of mind that's not permanent either.

Answer (score 0):

Using the given space and sacrificing time: All six dhātus, elements, are uncertain, subject to change, a burden and not own- or control-able, not worthy to fall for, not possible to hold as own, a pain, suffering. Okāsa (space, possibility, time, room) is one of that.

It runs out!